# Serilog in Azure Functions

Tags: c#, azure, dependency-injection, azure-functions, serilog

Each method in Azure Functions can have a `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger` injected into it for logging. Using `WebJobsStartup` with a startup class you can change the logging to use Serilog using the following syntax:

```cs
[assembly: WebJobsStartup(typeof(Startup))]
namespace MyFuncApp {
    public class Startup : IWebJobsStartup
    {
        public void Configure(IWebJobsBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Services.AddLogging(
                lb => lb.ClearProviders()
                    .AddSerilog(
                        new LoggerConfiguration()
                            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                            .WriteTo.Console()
                            .WriteTo.File(@"C:\Temp\MyFuncApp.log")
                            .CreateLogger(),
                        true));
        }
    }
}
```

I can also add other objects to the DI and inject them either into the methods or into the constructor for the class containing the methods using i.e. `builder.Services.AddSingleton<IMyInterface, MyImplementation>();`

However, I would very much like to be able to inject the `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger` in the same way, but if I try to use the `ILogger` in the constructor I get the following error during method invokation (as that's when the class is created):

> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger' while attempting to activate 'MyFuncApp.MyFunctions'.

So, is there any way of injecting the `ILogger` into a class constructor like this?

```cs
public class MyFunctions
{
    private IMyInterface _myImpl;
    private ILogger _log;

    public MyFunctions(
        IMyInterface myImplememtation, // This works
        ILogger log) // This does not
    {
        _myImpl = myImplementation;
        _log = log;
        _log.LogInformation("Class constructed");
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Function1([HttpTrigger() ... ) {
        _log.LogInformation("Function1 invoked");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the code below, it works at my side:

```
    [assembly: WebJobsStartup(typeof(Startup))]
    namespace MyApp
 {
        public class Startup : IWebJobsStartup
        {
            public void Configure(IWebJobsBuilder builder)
            {
                //other code

                builder.Services.AddLogging();
            }
        }



    public class Functions
    {
        //other code
        private ILogger _log;

        public Functions(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            _log = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Functions>();
        }

        [FunctionName("Token")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Function1(
            [HttpTrigger()]...)
        {
               _log.LogInformation("Function1 invoked");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Where do you configure Serilog with a `LoggerConfiguration`?

Comment: @GTHvidsten Please take a look at this [article](https://blog.bitscry.com/2019/04/05/dependency-injection-in-azure-functions/). And please let me know if any issues, then I take a look when I'm back. Thanks.

Comment: `ILoggerFactory.CreateLogger()` seems to work just fine in a constructor, and if I use the resulting logger in the methods the functionality seems to be identical to injecting the ILogger directly into the method. Thanks for the assist :)

Comment: have you simply tried:  ``public Functions(ILogger<Functions>  logger)``

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to further simplify the necessary setup by using the package [Anotar.Serilog.Fody](http://nuget.org/packages/Anotar.Serilog.Fody) (and any other [Anotar](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=anotar) package for that matter)

You need to set up Serilog all the same in the `Startup` class.

However, with the `Fody` package you can completely get rid of the injected logger

```
using Anotar.Serilog;

public class Functions
{
    [FunctionName("Token")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Function1(
        [HttpTrigger()]...)
    {
        // static calls to the LogTo class
        // get translated into proper Serilog code during build
        LogTo.Information("Function1 invoked");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With AzureFunctions v3, the pattern you outlined in your question works out-of-the box.