# How to add customDimensions and set operation_parentId for Azure function log

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

I created a http trigger V1 azure function on net framework 4.8, and used ILogger for logging. The code is like this.
[image]

I checked the Application Insight and queried for **traces** table. This table contains columns named **customDimensions** and **operation_ParentId**. May I ask is there anyway to add custom property in customDimensions column, or set a new Guid value for operation_ParentId? I know that I can use TelemetryClient sdk to create a custom telemetry client for logging. Just curious if there is any easy way which doesn't need to create a new telemetry client, because azure function offers bulit-in integration with application insight.

Also, since azure function runtimes automatically tracks requests, is there any way to change the operation_ParentId and customDimensions for **requests** table as well? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why would you want to set the `operation_ParentId`? It is used to correlate events and it shouldn't be set manually.

Comment: Got it. I just want to set a custom Guid value for tracking. Add it to customDimensions column is also fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

**To get both the headers and App Insights to get the custom operation Id, two things must be overridden.**

The first is an Activity that wraps the **`HttpClient`**, which is responsible for controlling the correlation headers and the other is App Insights' dependency tracing.

Although you can [disable Actions completely](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/19044) in your HttpClients, you can just remove the one in the client by setting `Activity.Current = null` to limit side effects.

```
var operationId = "CR" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
var url = "https://www.microsoft.com";
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    using (var requestMessage =
        new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url))
    {
        //Makes the headers configurable
        Activity.Current = null;

        //set correlation header manually
        requestMessage.Headers.Add("Request-Id", operationId);
        await client.SendAsync(requestMessage);
    }
}
```

The next step is to remove the App Insights default tracking [for this request](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore/issues/456). Again, you can disable dependency tracking completely, or you can [filter out the default telemetry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling) for this request. Processors are registered inside the Startup class just like initializers.

```
services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryProcessor<CustomFilter>();

public class CustomFilter : ITelemetryProcessor
{
    private ITelemetryProcessor Next { get; set; }

    // next will point to the next TelemetryProcessor in the chain.
    public CustomFilter(ITelemetryProcessor next)
    {
        this.Next = next;
    }

    public void Process(ITelemetry item)
    {
        // To filter out an item, return without calling the next processor.
        if (!OKtoSend(item)) { return; }

        this.Next.Process(item);
    }

    // Example: replace with your own criteria.
    private bool OKtoSend(ITelemetry item)
    {
        var dependency = item as DependencyTelemetry;

        if (dependency == null) return true;

        if (dependency.Type == "Http"
            && dependency.Data.Contains("microsoft.com")
            //This key is just there to help identify the custom tracking
            && !dependency.Context.GlobalProperties.ContainsKey("keep"))
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Finally, you must inject a telemetry client and call [`TelemetryClient.TrackDependency()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-dependencies#manually-tracking-dependencies) in the method that makes the remote call.

```
var operationId = "CR" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

//setup telemetry client
telemetry.Context.Operation.Id = operationId;
if (!telemetry.Context.GlobalProperties.ContainsKey("keep"))
{
    telemetry.Context.GlobalProperties.Add("keep", "true");
}
var startTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
var timer = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
//continue setting up context if needed

var url = "https:microsoft.com";
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    //Makes the headers configurable
    Activity.Current = null;

    using (var requestMessage =
        new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url))
    {
        //Makes the headers configurable
        Activity.Current = null;

        //set header manually
        requestMessage.Headers.Add("Request-Id", operationId);
        await client.SendAsync(requestMessage);
    }
}

//send custom telemetry 
telemetry.TrackDependency("Http", url, "myCall", startTime, timer.Elapsed, true);
```

Refer here more information.

Note: The above is possible by disabling the built-in dependency tracking and App Insights and handling it on your own. But the better approach is let .NET Core & App Insights do the tracking.

Comment: Finally we choose to upgrade our azure function to V3 use serilog https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55916750/serilog-in-azure-functions. It works well. Thanks anyway.