# content of operation_ParentId in application insights using W3C

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights, system.diagnostics

I'm currently using an `.NET 6.0 isolated` function with an `HTTP trigger`.

Because [the activity is not being filled](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/issues/914), I've added a middleware that creates the activity based on the W3C `traceparent` header.

My expectation based on [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/correlation) is that when using Application Insights, the `operation_ParentId` would relate directly to the `ParentSpanId` of an `Activity` where logging is done.

Yet that is not what I'm seeing. What I'm seeing is following

1. Application A sends a request using `traceparent = 00-3abe9f15e940badc5f1521e6eb1eb411-bfd30439c918c783-00`
2. In middleware of application B, an activity is started and a message is logged. I can also validate that the `ParentId` of the activity is equal to `00-3abe9f15e940badc5f1521e6eb1eb411-bfd30439c918c783-00`. The `ParentSpanId` is equal to `bfd30439c918c783`

```cs
using var requestActivity = new Activity(context.FunctionDefinition.Name);

requestActivity.SetParentId(traceParent);

requestActivity.Start();

_logger.LogInformation("Invoking '{Name}'", context.FunctionDefinition.Name);
```

3. In application insights I see `OperationId` being equal to the WC3 trace-id `3abe9f15e940badc5f1521e6eb1eb411` as expected. However, the `operation_ParentId` is a span I've not seen before. It is neither the `requestActivity.SpanId` nor the `requestActivity.ParentSpanId`.

What is happening that I do not understand? Does Application Insights not use the active `Activity` when logging?

my app configuration

```cs
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults(worker =>
    {
        worker.UseMiddleware<TracingMiddleware>();
    })
    .ConfigureServices(collection =>
    {
    })
    .ConfigureLogging(x=>x.AddApplicationInsights())
    .Build();

host.Run();
```

My middleware function

```cs
public async Task Invoke(FunctionContext context, FunctionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        using var requestActivity = new Activity(context.FunctionDefinition.Name);

        SetParentId(context, requestActivity);

        requestActivity.Start();

        _logger.LogInformation("Invoking '{Name}'", context.FunctionDefinition.Name);
        var t = Activity.Current;
        
        System.Console.WriteLine();
        System.Console.WriteLine($"Activity.TraceId: {t.TraceId}");
        System.Console.WriteLine($"Activity.ParentId: {t.ParentId}");
        System.Console.WriteLine($"Activity.SpanId: {t.SpanId}");

        await next(context);

        var statusCode = (context.Items != null)
            ? context.GetHttpResponseData()?.StatusCode
            : System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK;
        _logger.LogInformation(
            "Executed '{Name}', Result {Result}, Duration = {Duration}ms",
            context.FunctionDefinition.Name,
            statusCode,
            (DateTime.UtcNow - requestActivity.StartTimeUtc).TotalMilliseconds);

        requestActivity.Stop();
    }
```

**Update**
Firstly, Application Insights was/is in my opinion still not fully functioning properly for Isolated functions. Some values might get lost (e.g. [operation name](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/issues/1124)), but with little work, using the Application Insights SDK (e.g. `ITelemetryInitializer`) you can still add it consistently.

Related to differences in HTTP spans: When doing calls (e.g. HTTP calls), libraries can start new child activities. That is why you can get a different parent span coming in then you expect. The class that coordinates what to use when automagically passing trace information is the `DistributedContextPropagator`. I first did some changes to it based on [this post](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/41072#issuecomment-879395715) to get rid of that extra layer created by the child activity.
However, eventually we reverted that, because Application Insights likes it better when you keep as much default as you can. And getting a good overview in Application Insights (e.g. the application map) was way more important than having it perfectly aligned in my queried trace statements.

Answer (score 0):

As per the **[MS-Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/correlation#correlation-headers-using-w3c-tracecontext)** the Operation ID is equal to TraceId. And the Operation_parent Id has the combination of both Trace-ID with Parent-ID. The Format has **.**

> The `operation_ParentId` field is in the format
> `<trace-id>.<parent-id>`, where both `trace-id` and `parent-id` are
> taken from the trace header that was passed in the request.

I have noticed that It was not actually same. I have tired with many possible ways. I end up with The operation-ID is not equal to the Trace-ID and the Operation-parent-ID is not equal to < Trace-ID>.< Parent-ID>.

In my middle ware i have added the current context like below

```cs
             ILogger logger = context.GetLogger<MyCustomMiddleware>();

                //logger.LogInformation("From function: {message}", message);
            using var requestActivity = new Activity(context.FunctionDefinition.Name);
            //t.SetParentId(context, requestActivity);

       
        requestActivity.Start();

            logger.LogInformation("Invoking '{Name}'", context.FunctionDefinition.Name);

        //requestActivity.SetParentId(Convert.ToString(requestActivity.RootId));
        requestActivity.SetParentId(requestActivity.TraceId,requestActivity.SpanId,ActivityTraceFlags.None);
        var t = Activity.Current;
        //Activity.SetParentId(context, requestActivity,);
            //t.SetParentId(context, requestActivity)
        logger.LogInformation($"Activity.TraceId: {t.TraceId}");
        logger.LogInformation($"Activity.ParentId: {t.ParentId}");
        logger.LogInformation($"Activity.SpanId: {t.SpanId}");
        logger.LogInformation($"Activity.Id: {t.Id}");
        logger.LogInformation($"Activity.ParentSpanId: {t.ParentSpanId}");
        logger.LogInformation($"Activity.RootId: {t.RootId}");
        logger.LogInformation($"Activity.Parent: {t.Parent}");
```

Result I got.
[image]

Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72000378/15997690) for one of my workarounds with more details.