# Logging Azure Function

Tags: java, azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

Is there a way to view logging of my Azure Function App without the use of Application Insights?

Can I write the logging of my Function app to a separate file that I can view? (edit) If so, how?

Edit: I should have mentioned that I am using Java.

Comment: Sure, there's no tight coupling between Azure Functions and App Insights. You can use pretty much whatever you would use for an ASPNET web app. e.g. serilog, elmah, etc

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio My function is actually a Java Function, so not sure if you are able to give details on how I could write my logs to a separate file. My current Idea is to just store the logs in a list and then write them all to premade blob after the program is done executing. Problem is if the program crashes no logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Diagnostic Settings** will be of help here. You can enable diagnostics to publish the logs to a storage account.

To set the settings. Search for `Diagnostic settings` in the search-pane of your function app.
[image]
And then enable by providing the storage account details:
[image]

For full information refer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitor-log-analytics?tabs=java

The benefit of this is: that you can continue to log using the default logging framework that the azure-functions provide. There isn't any code change that is required.

Comment: Where in the storage account is it sending the logs? I set it up but am not sure where it is sending them.

Answer (score 0):

*yes, I do agree with the point mentioned by @Thiago Custodio. you can use serilog in the Azure functions to view your logs.*

*Here is the code provided by @Ivan Yang in this [So](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55931059) for using Serilg in Azure functions.*

```
  [assembly: WebJobsStartup(typeof(Startup))]
    namespace MyApp
 {
        public class Startup : IWebJobsStartup
        {
            public void Configure(IWebJobsBuilder builder)
            {
                //other code

                builder.Services.AddLogging();
            }
        }



    public class Functions
    {
        //other code
        private ILogger _log;

        public Functions(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            _log = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Functions>();
        }

        [FunctionName("Token")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Function1(
            [HttpTrigger()]...)
        {
               _log.LogInformation("Function1 invoked");
        }
    }

}
```